# Javascript converting ' to URL language

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple JavaScript function that works totally fine, until one of the variables has a ' in it.  This is what I tried:

```
    function search(champ1,champ2,role) {

    if((champ1!='')&&(champ2!='')){
        if((champ1!=champ2)) {
        var champ1_name = encodeURI(champ1);
        var champ2_name = encodeURI(champ2);
        var role_name = encodeURI(role);

        window.location.href="http://myurl.com/"+role_name+"/"+champ1_name+"&"+champ2_name;
        return false;
        } else if(champ1==champ2) {
            window.location.href="http://myurl.com/"+role;
        }
    }
}
```

but unfortunately when I run this script the URL still has the ' in it even after they ran through `encodeURI()`

Comment: Always prefer `encodeURIComponent` over `encodeURI`.

Comment: @MattBall I tried that as well and it seems like it's literally doing nothing.  Lets say when the function is run and `champ1 = it's`, when i do var `champ1_name = encodeURIComponent(champ1)` and then use `champ1_name` in the url, nothing is encoded and the ' still shows up in the URL

Comment: @user1895377 So, do you want to execute the `else` part if like `champ1 = it's` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to escape `'`, do something like `.replace("'", "%27")`. Or use a URL escaping function that lets you provide a string of characters that need to be escaped.

`decodeURIComponent("%27")` converts back to `"'"`.